# Difference between ContentValues and HashMap?

Tags: android

What is the difference between `ContentValues` and `HashMap`?   If there is a difference, what is the best analogy to describe it?

Comment: `ContentVaLues` has a method `writeToParcel (Parcel parcel, int flags)`

Answer (score 10):

**1)**[HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) is a general utility class that resides in [java.util](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/package-summary.html).
 [ContentValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) on the other hand is a specific class in [android.content](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/package-summary.html) designed to comply with Android classes like [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) and [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html)

**Note** that they implement different interfaces according to aforementioned designation:
- `HashMap` implements [Cloneable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)
- `ContentValues` implements [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

**2)** `ContentValues` has a member that is `HashMap` with `String` keys:

```
   private HashMap<String, Object> mValues
```

**3)** `ContentValues` has a number of methods to get and put typed values (like getAsFloat() etc)

**Conclusion**
You may consider `ContentValues` as a wrapper of `HashMap` to store typed values, usually along with Android [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) or [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html).
That's it

Answer (score 2):

first look at soruce code of ContetntValue.java class in below link

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/ContentValues.java

as you see this class has a Hash map variable (mValues) and almost all of methods work with it. e.g when you create a object of ContentValue you call ContentValue constructor and in this construtor mValue object has created e.g in line 52:

> public ContentValues(int size) {
>           mValues = new HashMap(size, 1.0f);
>       }

or when you call put method of a contentValue object in general you put value in a HashMap object(mValues) e.g line 95:

> public void put(String key, String value) {
>           mValues.put(key, value);
>       }

so why use ContentValue?!!
ContentValue has some useful methods that make it better for work with somethings like ContentResolver.One of the most important methods is writeToParcel():

> writeToParcel (Parcel parcel, int flags)

you can read about all of this methods in Android document:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html

hope this comment help you and sorry for my bad English.